# How to retain precision of arithmetic operation using AWK printf of column manipulation

Tags: awk, printf

I am trying to do simple division of columns using awk. However it always provides results with some rounding to some digits. How do I avoid that?

```
   cat input
    0.17292020834074046 0.17199272520432343 0.17019054988940305 0.16983492954097731
    0.22565582053882802 0.22452108440371940 0.22246477069620715 0.22201995331072724
```

I am trying to divide `$1/$3` and `$2/$4` by

```
awk '{print  $1/$3, $2/$4 }'  input 
awk '{printf "%s\t\n", $1/$3 "\t" $2/$4 }'  input
```

both of which are giving results up to some truncation.

```
1.01604 1.01271
1.01434 1.01127
```

Is it possible to print the complete result of division without any truncation as would have been provided by say `bc` calculator.

The desired output:

```
1.01603883678095673602 1.01270525250122645076
1.01434406819845869150 1.01126534374814371224
```

Answer (score 3):

With standard awk you will probably get inaccurate results. If you have GNU awk available you can achieve this with the `--bignum` flag and setting `OFMT` and `PREC` appropriately:

```
awk -M '{ print $1/$3, $2/$4 }' OFMT='%.20f' PREC=100 input
```

Output:

```
1.01603883678095673602 1.01270525250122645077
1.01434406819845869150 1.01126534374814371224
```

[This similar question on UL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57006/17666) might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{printf "%.20f\t%.20f\n", $1/$3,$2/$4 }'  Input_file
```

Comment: It does correctly, but for multiple columns do I have to do `%f` for each column I want to print or is there any global/short option if I want to have same precision for all columns I want to print.

Comment: @Boogeyman, you could use a loop may be for iterating in all fields and inside it call this? since no samples shown so I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

If `bc` is an option you could do the following with GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's:([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+):echo "scale=20; \1 / \3" | bc -l\necho "scale=20; \2 / \4" | bc -l:e; s/\n/ /'
```

With more portable sed:

```
{ 
  echo scale=20
  sed -E 's:([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+):\1 / \3\
\2 / \4:' input; 
}     | 
bc -l |
paste -d' ' - -
```

Output in both cases:

```
1.01603883678095673602 1.01270525250122645076
1.01434406819845869150 1.01126534374814371224
```